# How to create 2d sphere index using Codeigniter libraries and MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I had worked on MongoDB and Laravel 5.6 some days ago. I used the [Jenseggers Moloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) library to connect MongoDB and Laravel.

While using Jenseggers library, I needed to create 2dsphere index so that I could fetch data based on latitude and longitude using the geoJSON format. To set up 2dsphere index, I used this code (I didn't do it by native MongoDB method).

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('foursquare_places')->raw(function($collection) {
                  return $collection->createIndex([ 'loc' => '2dsphere' ]);
                });
```

Now, I want to use MongoDB with Codeigniter. I have found two libraries which are these:-

1. [**CImongo** library](https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library).
2. [**JIFT** Ci and MongoDB library](https://github.com/JIFT/codeigniter-mongodb-library).

However, I don't know how to create the 2dsphere index for a collection using both or any of these two libraries. 
**How can I create 2dsphere index in MongoDB, using these two libraries?**

Comment: Try to use the [recommended library](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter) instead of the deprecated and not maintained one.

Comment: Example of the "where_near" query: `$this->mongo_db->where(['loc' => ['$near' => [ $geometry => [ 'type' => 'Point',  'coordinates' => [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] ], '$minDistance' => 1000, '$maxDistance' => 5000 ] ] ])->get('foursquare_places');`

Comment: Oh Shit! I thought I need to use the `$this->mongo_db->command()` function in the library.

Comment: No, when you need something to get - you ask a query. When you need something to do - you command an order. The official library is a single file with less than 2k lines. Take a look at the code. It is way more sensible than the documentation.